# Optimization of points on a plane

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, geometry, discrete-geometry, plane-geometry

Suppose we have $n$ points on a plane. Let $D$ be the sum of the squares of all the pairwise distances between the points. Let $A$ be the area of the convex hull. What is the minimum possible value of $\frac{D}{A}$ and what arrangement achieves it for specific values of $n$?

Comment: I would think n=3 achieves the minimum, by looking at convex polygons and noting they have many diagonals. Probably one can show the equilateral triangle is optimal.  Gerhard "Try Thinking In The Small" Paseman, 2015.12.07.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I had meant to find the minimum value for each value of $n$ not to find the value of $n$ which achieves the minimum. By the way, it is pretty easy to prove that equilateral triangle is optimal for $n = 3$.

Comment: Then try dividing n into three groups, and arrange the groups in the form of an equilateral triangle.  I suspect that will do better than most arrangements.  Gerhard "Triangles Can Be Pretty Useful" Paseman, 2015.12.08

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I conjecture that the minimum is $2n$, for all $n\geq 4$.
This is obtained by putting four points in a square and the remaining points in the center.

There are then $(n-4)$ vertices in the center, and thus the total sum of distances squared is $4 \cdot \frac{1}{2}(n-4) + 4 + 2\cdot 2= 2n$,
assuming that the square has area $1$.

I ran many simulations using a genetic algorithm (here is the mathematica code):

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];

Mutate[ptList_,f_:0.1]:=ptList + f*RandomReal[{-1,1},{Length@ptList,2}];

Fitness[ptList_]:=Fitness[ptList]=Module[{aa,dd},
    aa=ConvexHullArea[ptList];
    dd=Total[(EuclideanDistance@@@Subsets[ptList,{2}])^2];
    dd/aa
];

RunSimulation[ptsLists_]:=Module[{newLists,j=1},
    newLists=ptsLists;

    Do[
        newLists[[k]] = Mutate[newLists[[j++]],0.01];
    ,{k,Ceiling[Length[newLists]/2],Length[newLists]}];

    newLists=SortBy[newLists,Fitness];

    gg=ListPlot[ newLists[[1]], Axes->False,PlotStyle->{PointSize[0.02]},
PlotLabel->("Fitness: " <>ToString@Fitness@newLists[[1]]),Frame->True,
AspectRatio->Automatic,FrameTicks->False ];

    newLists
];

Clear[gg]
Print[Dynamic[gg]];

init=RandomReal[{0,1},{100,9,2}];
pts=SortBy[init,Fitness];

Do[
pts=RunSimulation[pts];
,{1800}];
```

This code above runs 1800 generations with 100 lists, each with 9 points. However, looks like a pentagon with the remaining points in the middle is a local minima, so one has to restart a few times to see the square.

Comment: For $n = 4$, if you make an equilateral triangle with one point in the center I think you get $4\sqrt{3}$

Comment: @Halbort: I get it to be $16/\sqrt{3}$...

Comment: I just realized that I messed up.

Comment: It should be not too hard to show minimality by abstractly pushing dots around. Things inside the convex hull should gravitate toward a centroid, and points not too far outside the convex hull of the remaining points should be absorbable when there are at least 4 remaining points.  Gerhard "Hand Waving Gives Some Elevation" Paseman, 2015.12.08

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Yes, but I think you will find that a regular n-gon, with the remaining dots in the center is a local minima...
Perhaps one can argue that the ONLY local minima are of this form, and then it is easy to find which of these is global.

Comment: You may be right, but then I think you would have seen that in your simulation.  I suspect regular n-gons are minima only for n up to at most 6, because of the combinatorial explosion of diagonals.  Gerhard "Leaves The Numerics To Others" Paseman, 2015.12.08

Comment: How do I run this mathematica code on my machine?

Comment: @Halbort: Open a notebook, paste the code, and run. It dynamically updates a picture with the best configuration, and does 1800 generations.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Yeah, you are right, seems like 6-gons, 5-gons and 4-gons are stable, but maybe not higher...

Comment: Where does the image get stored?

Comment: I copy pasted it directly. I cannot see anything happening. Could you help me?

Comment: I keep getting {{k,Ceiling[Length[newLists$109483]/2],Length[newLists$109483]};\
newLists$109483=SortBy[newLists$109483,Fitness];gg=ListPlot[newLists$\
109483[[1]],Axes->False,PlotStyle->PointSize[0.02`]]} does not have \
appropriate bounds. >> as an error.

Comment: @Halbort: Oh, there was a brace missing at some point - it should work now. I use Mathematica 9, by the way.

Comment: I reached an equilibrium that involved a 7-gon. I think all regular polygons with some centroid points are equillibirum. The pentagon seems to be the most stable though.